# IOS prevent Location listen when app in background

Tags: ios, flutter

my app using package `geolocator: ^5.1.5`
I coding function listen to user location and when he near a point I notification him , it's work correctly but when app is open on screen but when press on home and put app in background it's push nothing but when resume app the app push notifications about location.

my function location listener

```
//? Listen option
var locationOptions = LocationOptions(
accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best, distanceFilter: 50);
//? listen
locationStreamListener =
    Geolocator().getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen(
  (Position position) async {
    //? latLng of current location
    LatLng currentLatlng = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    if(currentLatlng == myPointLocation){
        LocalNotificationsHelper(context).show(
         title: 'reach point',
         body:
         'there is action you have to do.',
         id: list.intId,
         payload: list.id);

    }

});
```

and this is my app permission on ios device

[image]

and these are info.plist values

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

My app x-code capabilities
[image]

Comment: You need to set "Background mode" as well in Xcode while building app.

Comment: @SaqibOmer I have add image for Capabilities xcode, do you mean I must check the location update

Comment: Check "Location udpdates"

Comment: Thanks I will try it